# Adding bottom row on column that sums the values of the entire column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table with five columns that has the following structure:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Timestamp</td>
         <td>Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Shop Name</td>
         <td>Amount</td>
         <td>Comments</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>72.75£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-11 16:53 Full Amount: 75 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>13/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>93.42£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:08 Full Amount: 96.31 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.8893</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>14/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>67.08£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:05 Full Amount: 69.15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.0745</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>18/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>94.00£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 96.91 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.9073</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>19/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>48.50£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 50 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>20/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>34.85£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:33 Full Amount: 35.93 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.0779</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>25/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Eastham Express</td>
         <td>212.97£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-02-01 10:51 Full Amount: 219.56 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 6.5868</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>03/02/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>14.55£</td>
         <td>Full Amount: 15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 0.45</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to sum the values of the Amount column and display a total amount in a row under the amount column. My question is, is there a way in which that can be done so that it can look like the picture below?[image]

So far the answers I've seen only added a table footer that displays under every column. Is it at all possible to add just 1 row?

Comment: You'll have to append a `<tr>` full of empty `<td>` except the one you want the total to be displayed in. Some quick CSS will get rid of the borders on your empty `<td>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this selector `'table tbody tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(4)'`

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var currencySymbol = '£'
var total = 0.0;
$('table tbody tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {
  total += parseFloat($(this).html().replace(currencySymbol, ''));
});

total += currencySymbol;

var $newTR = $("<tr><td colSpan='3'></td><td>"+total+"</td><td></td></tr>");
$('table tbody').append($newTR);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Timestamp</td>
         <td>Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Shop Name</td>
         <td>Amount</td>
         <td>Comments</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>72.75£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-11 16:53 Full Amount: 75 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>13/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>93.42£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:08 Full Amount: 96.31 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.8893</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>14/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>67.08£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:05 Full Amount: 69.15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.0745</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>18/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>94.00£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 96.91 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.9073</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>19/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>48.50£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 50 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>20/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>34.85£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:33 Full Amount: 35.93 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.0779</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>25/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Eastham Express</td>
         <td>212.97£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-02-01 10:51 Full Amount: 219.56 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 6.5868</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>03/02/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>14.55£</td>
         <td>Full Amount: 15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 0.45</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

See? the total amount was calculated.

## Resources

- [`:nth-child() Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)
- [`:gt() Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Try keeping the info in a JSON file, then generating the table with Javascript's `createElement()` and `appendChild()` methods. With all the information in the JSON file, you can easily sum the amounts and add another node at the end of each table row with special formatting with the `:last-child` selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can **append a total row** to the `table`

```
function addTotalRow()
{
   //remove existing total row
   $( ".table-bordered tr.totalRow" ).remove();

   //sum of all values
   var sum = 0;
   $( ".table-bordered tr" ).each( function(){
     var fourthTdValue = parseFloat( $(this).find("td:eq(3)").text() ); //get 4th td value and parseFloat the same
     sum += isNaN( fourthTdValue ) ? 0 : fourthTdValue;
   });

   //append the total row
   $( ".table-bordered" ).append( "<tr class='totalRow'><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>" + sum + "£</td><td></td></tr>" )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, you can simply append a nearly empty `<tr>` to your table :

```
var total = 0;
$('table tr:not(:first) td:nth-of-type(4)').each(function(){
  total += +$(this).text().slice(0,-1);
});

$('table').append('<tr><td class="no-border"></td><td class="no-border"></td><td class="no-border"></td><td>'+total+'£</td><td class="no-border"></td></tr>');
```

```js
var total = 0;
$('table tr:not(:first) td:nth-of-type(4)').each(function(){
  total += +$(this).text().slice(0,-1);
});

$('table').append('<tr><td class="no-border"></td><td class="no-border"></td><td class="no-border"></td><td>'+total+'£</td><td class="no-border"></td></tr>');
```

```css
table{
  border: none !important;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td{
  border: 1px solid black !important;
}

.no-border{
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Timestamp</td>
         <td>Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Shop Name</td>
         <td>Amount</td>
         <td>Comments</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>72.75£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-11 16:53 Full Amount: 75 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>13/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>93.42£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:08 Full Amount: 96.31 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.8893</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>14/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>67.08£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:05 Full Amount: 69.15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.0745</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>18/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>94.00£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 96.91 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.9073</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>19/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>48.50£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 50 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>20/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>34.85£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:33 Full Amount: 35.93 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.0779</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>25/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Eastham Express</td>
         <td>212.97£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-02-01 10:51 Full Amount: 219.56 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 6.5868</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>03/02/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>14.55£</td>
         <td>Full Amount: 15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 0.45</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var amount = 0;
$('tr').not(':first').not(':last').each(function(i, item){
  amount += parseFloat($(item).children().eq(3).text());
});

$('.total').text(amount + '£');
```

```css
.table-bordered{
  border: none !important;
}
tr:last-child > td{
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.total{
  border: 1px solid black !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Timestamp</td>
         <td>Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Shop Name</td>
         <td>Amount</td>
         <td>Comments</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>72.75£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-11 16:53 Full Amount: 75 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>13/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>93.42£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:08 Full Amount: 96.31 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.8893</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>14/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>67.08£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:05 Full Amount: 69.15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.0745</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>18/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>94.00£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 96.91 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.9073</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>19/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>48.50£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 50 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>20/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>34.85£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:33 Full Amount: 35.93 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.0779</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>25/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Eastham Express</td>
         <td>212.97£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-02-01 10:51 Full Amount: 219.56 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 6.5868</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>03/02/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>14.55£</td>
         <td>Full Amount: 15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 0.45</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td class="total"></td><td></td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an DOM attribute called `colspan`, it is used to control how many columns does a `<td>` cross over.

You can add a row and some CSS to do the trick:

```
<style>
    tr:last-child>td[colspan] {
        border: none;
    }
</style>
<table>
    ...
    <tr><td colspan="3"></td><td>638.12€</td><td colspan="1"></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append footer, and just style borders with css

```js
var tds = $('.table-bordered tr:not(:first-child) td:nth-child(4)')

var amount = 0;
tds.each(function(k, td) {
  amount += parseFloat($(td).text().substring(-1, $(td).text().length - 1));
})
$('.table-bordered').append('<tfoot><tr><td colspan="3"></td><td>' + amount + '£</td><td></td><tr>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Timestamp</td>
         <td>Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Shop Name</td>
         <td>Amount</td>
         <td>Comments</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>10/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>72.75£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-11 16:53 Full Amount: 75 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>13/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>93.42£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:08 Full Amount: 96.31 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.8893</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>14/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>67.08£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-18 10:05 Full Amount: 69.15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.0745</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>18/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>94.00£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 96.91 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 2.9073</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>19/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>48.50£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:34 Full Amount: 50 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>20/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Mexican House</td>
         <td>34.85£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-01-25 10:33 Full Amount: 35.93 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 1.0779</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>25/01/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>Eastham Express</td>
         <td>212.97£</td>
         <td>PAID 2018-02-01 10:51 Full Amount: 219.56 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 6.5868</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>03/02/2018</td>
         <td>New Delhi Cash &amp; Carry</td>
         <td>J's Pizza Stop </td>
         <td>14.55£</td>
         <td>Full Amount: 15 Discount of 3% Discount Total: 0.45</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```